# Magento 2.4.1 Error Current customer does not have an active cart. & Something went wrong with your request. Please try again later

Tags: magento2

I have a new install and I get two errors after I click on **Place Order**. I am using the Payment Method  **Check/Money order** The following two red boxes say the following.

> ```
> Something went Wrong with your request. Please try again later. 
> Current customer does not have an active cart.
> ```

I have tried many things and continue to get this error.

Comment: your use localhost ?

Comment: No, I am using a web server with a domain name and subdomain.